# awk not printing header in output file

Tags: awk

The below `awk` seems to work great with `1` issue, the header lines do hot print in the output? I have been staring at this awhile with no luck.  What am I missing?  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} FNR==1 || ($7 in a)' /home/panels/file1 test.txt | 
awk '{split($2,a,"-"); print a[1] "\t" $0}' | 
sort | 
cut -f2-> /home/panels/test_filtered.vcf
```

**test.txt** (used in the `awk` to give the filtered output  --only a small portion of the data but the tab delimited format is shown)

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    949608  949608  G   A
```

**current output** (has no header)

```
chr1    949608  949608  G   A
```

**desired output** (has header)

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    949608  949608  G   A
```

Comment: can you provide sample of file1 as well? Also, try to narrow down the problem by removing the superfluous pipes like `sort`, `cut` and maybe one of the `awk`s. That is, what part is exactly failing?

Comment: Your headers are going to sort, and are probably intermingled with your data.

Comment: The headers were intermingled with the data, removing the sort worked.  Can you please make that an answer @WilliamPursell so I can accept it?  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the header is going to sort, and getting mixed in with your data.  A simple solution is to do:

```
... | { read line; echo $line; sort; } |
```

to prevent the first line from going to sort.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how this prevents the first line to be skipped? I test it with `seq 2 10 | { read line; echo $line; sort; }` and works fine, only that I don't really understand how it does it.

Comment: `read line` reads data from stdin one character at a time until it sees a newline and stores that line in the variable `line`.  Then the shell prints that line.  Then sort starts up and consumes the rest of stdin.  This behavior is only possible because `read` reads exactly one character at a time, and is (I believe) the reason `read` behaves that way.

Comment: Aaah right, I see. So for example `{ read line; read line; echo $line; }` would just print the second line, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can combine your scripts and add the sort into `awk` and handle header this way.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]; next} 
        FNR==1{print "dummy\t" $0; next}
       $7 in a{split($2,b,"-"); print b[1] "\t" $0 | "sort" }' file1 file2 |
  cut -f2
```